# Is this a correct way of initializing struct sockaddr_in.sin_zero[8] as 0?

Tags: c++, c, struct, memset

I am doing this right now but

```
struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
inet_aton("10.12.110.57", &(my_addr.sin_addr));
memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);
```

can I do this? Will this also zero the rest of the struct? i.e.`sin_zero[8]`

```
struct sockaddr_in my_addr = {AF_INET, htons(MYPORT), 0};
// Or
struct sockaddr_in my_addr = {AF_INET, htons(MYPORT), {0} };
```

Comment: Both will work. And as Matt McNabb has mentioned in his answer,  designated initializers as in second case will make the code more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Of course you could just write `0` which is less verbose than `'\0'`. Also you could replace `8` by `sizeof my_addr.sin_zero` to make sure you are setting the right number of bytes.

A tidier way is:

```
struct sockaddr_in my_addr = { 0 };
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
```

If you want to use a brace-enclosed initializer for the whole thing then I'd suggest using designated initializers for readability. Also this may or may not be possible, as in some situations braced initializers have to be constant expressions and it's not clear whether MYPORT is a variable or not.

Comment: @MattMcNabb i deleted that comment I fixed the code in the question.
So all three of my methods are correct?

Comment: @pizzaEatingGuy yes, although you should go with what is more robust and easily seen to be correct (i.e. so someone checking your code doesn't need to look up documentation to see if you got the right number of bytes in memset, or the right order of braced initializers)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to value-initialize a struct in C++11 is to simply add a brace-or-equal initializer and let [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) do the work:

```
sockaddr_in my_addr {};
```

In C++03:

```
sockaddr_in my_addr = {};
```

By the way, [sin_zero](http://www.opengroup.org/platform/resolutions/bwg2001-many.html) has been removed per The Open Group Base Resolution bwg2001-004. Depending on your platform, you may no longer have to care about that member variable.